# XML remove child node by attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i have a xml file for my player's settings. Here is my xml file

```
<Player>
 <Volume Value="0,4044944" />
  <Playlist>
   <Song Path="E:\Music\Main\Chipmunk ft. Chris Brown - Champion (Explicit Version).mp3" />
    <Song Path="E:\Music\Main\Usher - More (RedOne Jimmy Joker Remix).mp3" />
 </Playlist>
  <LastPosition LastSong="" Position="" />
 </Player>
```

I want to make a button which removes the node with the selected path. I have variable "path" which keeps the directory info. When i put the code :

```
Doc.Descendants("Song").Where(p => p.Element("Path").Value == path).FirstOrDefault().Remove();
```

i get a System.NullReferenceException . Can u assist me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be `p.Attribute`, not `p.Element`.